# How to make a regex to remove all special char (?.=+, etc), but should allow Chinese/Japan/Korean char

Tags: php, regex

Chinese/Japan/Korean char is double-byte or Unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex should work; `\p{P}` matches punctuations and `\p{S}` [matches symbols](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

```
preg_replace("/\p{P}|\p{S}/u", "", $s);
```

I couldn't test it because my pcre doesn't support `\p`, `\x` etc. I got the error:

> PHP Warning:  `preg_replace()`: Compilation failed: support for `\P`, `\p`, and `\X` has not been compiled at offset 1 in test.php on line 3

If you get this error, this page [describes a fix](http://chrisjean.com/2009/01/31/unicode-support-on-centos-52-with-php-and-pcre/)

Answer (score 1):

The [mb_ereg](http://php.net/manual/de/book.mbstring.php) functions implement multibyte-aware regexes. However, you really need to specify more exactly what you mean by "special char".

**Edit:** I think what you need is the [Unicode character classes](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.unicode.php) supported in PCRE, but I'm not sure whether these are supported by the mb_ereg functions or whether the preg functions work with multibyte strings.

Comment: all that are not language char or digital is the "special"