# PHP: Check only chars

Tags: php

How can i check whether a variable contains only chars and not numbers?

I checked out is_string, but then you could kind of hack it if you make the variable "123"..

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ctype_alpha()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php).

> Checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, are alphabetic.

Note that this function seems to be locale specific, so if you want to test for Umlauts /  accented characters, you may have to set the correct locale first.

If using locales is not an option, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245823/how-to-make-a-regex-to-remove-all-special-char-etc-but-should-allow-chin) is a regex-based approach that promises to detect Unicode symbols in all languages, which would be the perfect approach if it works (I haven't tested it myself).

Comment: I just tested ctypep_alpha and It wont allow "Name LName" but it allows "NameLNAME" .. if theres spaces it returns false. And tried NameLNÄÖ returns false even when i did setlocale(LC_ALL, 'swedish');

Comment: also tried the preg_match suggestion, preg_replace("/\p{P}|\p{S}/u", "", $var)) , returns true even when the $var is : NAME NÄÖME123?!#¤

Comment: @Karem try `{L}` instead of `{S}`, that might do the trick. More on character classes here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: ok starts to work, although it only works if no space between the first and lastname..How can i fix this

Comment: @Karem I don't know, I'm not into Regexes much. I would consider just str_replace() ing the spaces before the check

Answer (score 2):

[`ctype_alpha()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) is what you're looking for.

From the docs:

> Checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, are alphabetic.
>
> In the standard C locale letters are just [A-Za-z] and `ctype_alpha()` is equivalent to `(ctype_upper($text) || ctype_lower($text))` if `$text` is just a single character, but other languages have letters that are considered neither upper nor lower case.

Usage:

```
if(ctype_alpha($string)) {
  //variable is characters only
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, please look the issue im having in @Pekka´s answers comment