# can some one tell me how valid letter only by php regex

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Check only chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773825/php-check-only-chars)

i want insert only character from A to Z how i can make it by regular expression

Comment: *(tutorial)* [Regex patterns](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)

Comment: may be better to use filter_var() function to validate this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ereg('[^A-Za-z]', $text)) {
  echo "More then letters";
}

else {
  echo "only letters";    
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: `ereg` is **deprecated** and **slow**. Use `preg_match` instead.